# Django Template set of sets

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

Is it possible to access a set of a set in django template.

ie. a.b_set.c_set.count

so it gets a count of all c objects related to all b objects which are related to c.

I know I can make a query in the backend ie c.objects.filter(b__a=a), however I wish to do it from the template alone.

Cheers,
Emmet

Answer (score 0):

This may not be possible to do from the template, since it was never intended to use "complex" logic. You should do it in the view. 
Since what you want to get is a new attribute "per queryset", this is no one-liner.

Example:

```
as = a.objects.all()
for a in as:
    a.b_c_count = c.objects.filter(b__a=a).count()
```

And use it like that in the template:

```
a.b_c_count
```

If you have a lot of a objects, this will be a bottleneck, so you may want to try the [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) method (and use as = a.objects.all().extra(*parameters)), or even raw sql.